# User access token using to get facebook ads performance data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token, facebook-ads-api

I try to get ads performance data using this api: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/{ad-account-id}/insights. User access token is needed when doing this request. I have several ad accounts. But one user access token is valid just for part of my ads accounts. The error message is "(#10) You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this action". Why?  (I can access the dashboard report of all ad accounts.)

Every user access token is related to an app. I have two user access tokens which are generated with different apps. If I change to another access tokens, the ad accounts of which I can get performance data by api are different. So I guess this is related to apps by which user access token is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Access tokens are made of up a user + app. Make sure both the user, and the app have access entity you're trying to access (in this case, ad account).

Also, when generating the token make scope includes the permission for `ads_read`